# Access signal name in Simulink directly

Tags: label, signals, simulink

Is there a way to access a signal's name in Simulink and then, for example, write it into a constant block?

I know there is the get_param command for MATLAB, but this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to go via `get_param` using the block from which the signal originates, e.g.:

```
p = get_param(gcb, 'PortHandles');
l = get_param(p.Outport, 'Line');
sig_name = get_param(l, 'Name');
```

See [Signal Names and Labels](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/signal-names.html) in the Simulink documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to write the signal to the Matlab workspace with the "To Workspace" block. You could then again access it by using `assignin`. See http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html

Don't forget to use `set_param(bdroot,'SimulationCommand','update')` to update your simulation with the new value, see http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-set-param-command.html